# Using item-text as a function to customize Vietify v-combobox items

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'd like to customize my combobox items, to as using item-text prop as described here:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox

Here is a fork of a vuetify example where I define a function whick always returns 'test':

```
:item-text="() => 'test'"
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yWxQdN?editors=1010

Is there a reason why my function is not called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your Codepen example, instead of the `item-text` property, use the `selection` *scoped slot*.

```
<v-combobox :items="items">
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{item, index}">
        {{ yourFunc() }}
    </template>
</v-combobox>
```

Comment: This is the solution I finally chose, even if I didn't want to redefine the whole item template.

Answer (score 0):

As said in documentation, "item-text" seems to be used only if items are objects, and not if they are primitives.

> **When using objects**, will look for a text and value field. This can be
>   changed using the item-text and item-value props